# How to change datatype VARCHAR to DATETIME?

Tags: sql-server

My current Database column's datatype is `varchar`, but I want to alter it to `datetime`. I use this sqlserver code to alter it, but failed.

```
ALTER TABLE Logbook
ALTER COLUMN Company_Date datetime NOT NULL;
```

Result:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
> in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option here might be to use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
ALTER TABLE Logbook ADD COLUMN Company_Date1 datetime;

UPDATE Logbook
SET Company_Date1 = TRY_CONVERT(datetime, Company_Date);

ALTER TABLE Logbook DROP COLUMN Company_Date;
sp_rename 'Logbook.Company_Date1', 'Company_Date', 'COLUMN';
```

The strategy here is to create a new datetime column `Company_Date1` which is a bona fide datetime column.  Then, we update it using `TRY_CONVERT` against the text values in `Company_Date`.  Note that should the conversion not be possible, there would be no error, but instead a `NULL` would be returned.  Finally we drop the original text `Company_Date` column and rename `Company_Date1` to `Company_Date`.

Answer (score 1):

you have some bad data in column one way you can use isdate function before alter column such as

```
update logbook set company_date=null where isdate(company_date)=0
```

after that alter column

another way select the list of bad data and correct it then alter column